# Make Windows 11 sleep instead of shutdown during power outage

Tags: windows-11, power, shutdown

Just upgraded to windows 11 and noticed that during a power outage the PC shuts down. With windows 10 the PC would sleep (or hibernate) instead of shut down and when the power was on again I had all my stuff opened and ready to resume work.

How can I set this to happen also in WIndows 11? Thank you!

Comment: This would require you disable Hybrid Shutdown, by doing this, you revert to the hardware dependencies of going to sleep, which requires drivers. Are you sure you want to revert back to the legacy version of a sleep state. Hybrid Shutdown should make it so your system nearly instantly resumes from its state.

Comment: It does not. That`s the problem. It actually shuts down and all is back to zero. Nothing resumes instantly, I have to wait for windows to start and then reopen everithing.

Comment: So did you disable hybrid shutdown which requires a hibernation file?

Comment: I did not. All I did was to upgrade to Win11. I googled and found this hbernation and hybrid shutdown issue, I enabled the hibernation which was missing from the menu and enabled the hybrid shutdown by cmd as I found googling. Will wait and see it if this fixed it. 
Thank you for you help! Will get back in one week or so with an update if any power outage will happen again.